# Why are stability circles circles on a Smith chart?

Tags: amplifier, stability, smith-chart

I am new to basic concepts in amplifier stability, so the question might seem obvious, sorry if it is the case.

The amplifier stability translates into  the equations for the reflection coefficients in load and source plain. The stability circle in the source plain will be
\begin{equation}
|\Gamma_S - C_L| = r_L
\end{equation}

where \$\Gamma_S\$ is a source reflection coefficient, \$C_L\$ is a circle center, \$r_l\$ is a radius of the circle. I know that if we plot the equation on the Smith chart, it will be a circle.

Why is it a circle? Is there a mathematical explanation for it? I can understand that in a Cartesian coordinates that would be a case, but it is not clear for the Smith chart.

Comment: Remember how is obtained Smith chart? It is a transformation that "transforms" cartesian coordinates (x,y) onto Smith coordinates through reflection coefficient (abs(rho), phase (rho)). Remember also what is "stability" (isn't where the real part of the "impedance" became "negative")?

Comment: Something as this could help ? http://www.highfrequencyelectronics.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2473:understanding-stability-circles&catid=215&Itemid=189  and this https://mixsignal.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/481lecture34.pdf

Comment: There is a rule that a circle on the polar plot of reflection coefficient will also be a circle on the Smith chart (and vice versa). But I don't think I've ever seen the actual proof of it.

Comment: @The Photon  ... I don't remember how this transformation is called. But If I remember well ... lines, in the x,y plane, are transformed into circles into the Smith Chart. So, if a Line is a limit to a circle ... a circle transforms into a circle. When the lines are perpendicular, the resulting circles are "orthogonal". A mathematician would help. The demonstration is done in the link just before ...

Comment: @Antonio51, it should be conformal transform

Comment: I have checked, it seems that the transformation is probably linear fractional one, and there is a theorem that says that any circle stays circle after this transformation

Comment: @PierrePolovodov Ok. Did you find the demonstration of what you search in the link I provide here ? https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Microwave_and_RF_Design_V%3A_Amplifiers_and_Oscillators_(Steer)/02%3A_Linear_Amplifiers/2.06%3A_Amplifier_Stability  fig 2.6.14 -->fig 2.6.25

Comment: @Antonio51, thank you for you links. The last one explains very well how we get the equations for the circles. I was searching however how these equations translate into circles. The answer is somewhere in the complex function theory somewhere.

Comment: To "see" the circle and convince me they are circles, I would take the formulas and "plot" the points into Smith Chart for the variable used (which is complex). Ex: for output stability (EE&O, formulas 2.6.24 and 2.6.25), I should vary |S11| with condition |S11|=|x+j y|=1 (which is a circle...). Ok, it is not a "simple" task.

Comment: There should be a plotting on a Smith chart in QUCS software for ex. I haven't checked it yet